# Recommended setup for sharing Internet access with neighbor

Tags: networking, home-networking

I own a single-family detached home, and the single-family detached home next door which is a rental property. I'm looking to provide Internet to the rental property, by sharing my main home's Internet connection (mostly for cost savings).

I'm looking to ensure the following:

- Wired connectivity to the second home, Wi-Fi inside of it. The homes are too far apart for Wi-Fi to carry from one to the other, but close enough that a Cat6 run should work.
- Traffic isolation. I don't want to see my neighbor's printer on my LAN nor do I want to see theirs.
- Performance isolation. I don't want my high-bandwidth service consumption to affect them, and vice versa.

I think I can make this work reasonably well by using a VLAN for traffic isolation? Are there things I should know about when connecting two homes via Cat6 cable? Am I overlooking a radically simpler solution?